# send email with ics file and body template

Tags: cakephp

Please could anyone help me, i need to send a calendar invitation to users. I'm developping in CakePHP 2.0, the problem i'm getting is that the email is sent with the header VCALENDAR but not the body template.

```
          $lieu = $this->Controller->request->data ['User']['lieu'];
        $objet = 'objet';//message type
        $loc= $lieu;
        $vcal = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
        $vcal .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
        $vcal .= "PRODID:-//testa//test//EN\r\n";
        $vcal .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
        $vcal .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
        $vcal .= "UID:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."-domain.com\r\n";
        $vcal .= "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\r\n";
        $vcal .= "DTSTART:$start\r\n";
        $vcal .= "DTEND:$end\r\n";
        $vcal       .=  "ORGANIZER;CN=Admin:MAILTO:admin@admin.org\r\n";           
        $vcal       .= "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=$mail[$iduser]:MAILTO:$mail[$iduser]\r\n";
        //$vcal .= "DTEND:$end\r\n";
        if ($loc != "") $vcal .= "LOCATION:$loc\r\n";
        $vcal .= "SUMMARY:$objet\r\n";
        $vcal .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
        $vcal .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
        $vcal .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
        $vcal .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
        $vcal .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
        $vcal .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
        $vcal .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";
        $headers = "\r\nMIME-version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"";
        $headers .= "\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"messages.ics\"";
        $headers .= "\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nX-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0";
        $Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
        $Email->to($mail);
        $Email->subject($objet);
        $Email->replyTo('admin@admin.org');
        $Email->from ('admin@admin.org');
        $Email->template('message');
        $Email->setHeaders(array($headers));
        $Email->emailFormat ('html','text');
        $Email->send($vcal);
```

Comment: Where are you using `$headers`? These should be being passed as an associative array to `$Email->setHeaders()`.

Comment: I use following  $Email->template('message');

Comment: My problem is that I can not get sent the email with the header and template.